# Any way to hide the 'image is loading' png Google Chrome shows?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I use a custom loading spinner for images and video, but Chrome specifically insists on showing this little photo placeholder while an  is loading, which means it overlaps in an unpleasant way with my loading spinner (see attachment). I don't want to just bump my spinner up above the Google sprite using a z-index because I like that when the image/video does appear it shows above the spinner from the first frame.

Any ideas how to disable that Google's image sprite in the HTML/CSS?

[image]

HTML: (src is set via a URL param)

```
<body>
    <div class="mediaWrapper isLoading">
          <img id="media" src="" />
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      setURLParams()
    </script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function setURLParams() {
    var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    document.getElementById("media").setAttribute("src", params.get('file'));
}
```

Comment: Your code, please...

Comment: is this only happening in chrome, or other browsers as well? what is the `src` property value in the HTML, and are you changing the `src` value in some way?

Comment: if I were you, I'd hide the image with `clip-path:circle(0)` until the `onload` event is fired and then show it again

Comment: Will edit the post to show; but I'm running a function setURLParams() which takes the file path from the URL and sets it to the img src. Yes, only happens in chrome.

Comment: Update your code to have the image hidden by default and show/set src when loaded. Setting an empty src doesn't make sense. There's nothing to see.